# Text doesn't display on the title screen button

Tags: pygame

I've been having trouble trying to display the title menu text when making a game. I'm trying to display the font on the button so that when I hover my mouse over the button, the font stays on the screen.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

background_colour = (33, 37, 49)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 600))

pygame.display.set_caption('A Game')

screen.fill(background_colour)

game_font = pygame.font.Font('JetBrainsMono-Regular.ttf', 50)
game_name = game_font.render('a game', True, (255, 255, 255))
game_name = pygame.transform.scale2x(game_name)
game_name_rect = game_name.get_rect(center=(500, 300))
pygame.draw.rect(screen, (38, 44, 60), game_name_rect)

running = True
title_screen = True

while running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    if title_screen is True:
        screen.blit(game_name, game_name_rect)

        if not game_name_rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (38, 44, 60), game_name_rect)

        if game_name_rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (58, 64, 80), game_name_rect)

    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to draw the text after the rectangle:

```py
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    if title_screen is True:
        color = (38, 44, 60)
        if game_name_rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            color = (58, 64, 80)

        pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, game_name_rect)
        screen.blit(game_name, game_name_rect)
   
    pygame.display.update()
```